# Configure Telerik Reporting with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am following this article on how to configure Telerik Reporting on ASP.NET MVC 5 and .NET 4.6.1 [Using HTML5 ASP.NET MVC Report Viewer in a web application](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/html5-mvc-report-viewer-embedding) then [Telerik Reporting REST Web API to Web Application](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/telerik-reporting-rest-host-http-service-using-web-hosting)

One thing I could not do in this is Register routes
[image]

If I do it, I get following error. I think its conflicting with some other routes, not sure where it is...
[image]
[image]

I tried commenting out MVC routes registration, that also gives same error

```
//RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

> A route named 'Resources' is already in the route collection. Route
>   names must be unique. Parameter name: name

So without registering the route when I do POST call to the following URL I get good response.
[image]

But If I try to verify the reports as per the documentation I get the following error
[image]
Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**

---

Route issue is fixed. removed a duplicate entry in WebApiConfig initialization

When access this URL **http://localhost:[portnumber]/api/reports/formats**
Following error is still not resolved

> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"The type
>   initializer for
>   'Telerik.Reporting.Processing.RenderingExtensionManager' threw an
>   exception.","exceptionType":"System.TypeInitializationException","stackTrace":"
>   at
>   Telerik.Reporting.Services.Engine.ReportEngine.ListRenderingExtensions()\r\n
>   at
>   Telerik.Reporting.Services.WebApi.ReportsControllerBase.GetDocumentFormats()\r\n
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass6_2.b__2(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__6.MoveNext()"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this section in web.config i removed it and it worked fine

```
<section name="Telerik.Reporting" type="Telerik.Reporting.Configuration.ReportingConfigurationSection, Telerik.Reporting, Version=12.2.18.1129, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a9d7983dfcc261be" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that following line does'nt occurs twice in `Application_Start` then go into the `bin folder of project`, `delete` all `DLL` files becouse  if your old `assemblies` are still part of that, you might be still getting `duplicate routes`. and then `rebuild` the `project` this will solve this problem,

Comment: route error is fixed. I found a duplicate entry so removed it.